# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL: recordingDelegate: is not calling delegate

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I am trying to capture video using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. For that I am using sample code of apple. I don't have great uderstanding on this but for start video capture I am using following code:

```
-(void)startRecordingWithOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)videoOrientation;
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [AVCamUtilities connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self movieFileOutput] connections]];
    if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
       [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:videoOrientation];

    [[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self outputFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];
 // After this method my session say recording is yes.
}
```

Here:

`[self movieFileOutput]` returning a object of `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.
Now I have delegate methods for handling further things.

The problamatic part is Delegate Methods for `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` are being called sometime and some time this doesn't. 
Max probably when I pop this page after first recording and then I come back on this screen I face that delegate methods are not being called.
I have to Kill application and this works for new recording.

Please tell me the solution.

EDIT: The delegate method calls only once when I delete application and than reinstall app. After that this never get called. Even If I don't capture video and come on the screen and go back delegate don't get called. I am using apple's AVCam demo and added a screen before recorder screen.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the file you trying to save doesnt exist yet?
If it does, movie capture will fail to start, hence no delegane methods will be called.